# Creating an array of unknown depth from model relationships

Tags: ruby

So this seems like a simple problem but I'm struggling to find a solution.

I have a list of pages, some pages have child pages and some of those children have their own child pages. I want to create a way of listing all the pages in order with their child pages.

I'm aiming for this ouput:

```
page_1
  page_1a
page_2
  page_2a
  page_2b
    page_2bi
    page_2bii
    page_2biii
  page_2c
page_3
page_4
page_5
```

(the actual output I'm looking for is an array that I can then print out like this in my view).

This would be very easy if I used nested `each` statements but I want something that is agnostic about the depth of nesting. I need something that can produce the correct output regardless of the number of levels that have been nested.

I have played around to find a solution to this and came up with the code below. The problem with this code is that once it nests in, it doesn't find the remaining siblings of the nested pages' parent - in other words, it stops and moves to the next top level page after it has found a nested page.

```ruby
def print_page_hierarchy
  output = []
  Page.top_level.each do |p|
    level = 0
    keep_looping = true
    output << [p.title]
    while keep_looping
      if p.children?
        level += 1
        nested_pages = p.children
        for p in nested_pages
          output << [" "*(level*2)+p.title]
          if p.children?
            nested_pages = p.children # p.children returns an array of child pages
            keep_looping = true
            break
          end
        end
      else
        keep_looping = false
      end
    end
  end
  output
end
```

How can I make this work?

Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

**EDIT**

The input is a series of associations. A page has a parent_page_id and has the methods `parent` and `children`. I don't have an initial array, just associations.
This doesn't matter too much because the question is about how to approach recursion. You can assume this is an array for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I can give you a good idea to build an xml with this logic.

Comment: This is a perfect example of a problem that should be solved with a recursive function: A function that return the current level of nodes plus the result of the same function of the level below. Wanna give it a try or you need more help. Btw there are gems for this, `awesome_nested_set` for example.

Comment: You showed the output you want, but have not shown what structure it has.

Comment: @spickermann I'm trying to understand how to solve this rather than using a gem but thanks for the suggestion. It would be great if you could give a little example of a recursive function for this problem. I understand the concept but can't see how to apply it.

Comment: @sawa and Arup Rakshit -- I am not too concerned with the specifics of the output except that it be an array (not xml). My example effectively shows a flat array with varying levels of indentation. The how is more important that the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare some input. I assume you have a an array of nodes and each node has a name and children:

```
class Node < Struct.new(:name, :children); end
nodes = [ Node.new(:page_1, [ Node.new(:page_1a) ]),
          Node.new(:page_2, [ Node.new(:page_2a),
                              Node.new(:page_2b, [ Node.new(:page_2bi),
                                                   Node.new(:page_2bii),
                                                   Node.new(:page_2biii) ]),
                              Node.new(:page_2c) ]),
          Node.new(:page_3),
          Node.new(:page_4),
          Node.new(:page_5) ]
```

The recursive method:

```
def print_page_hierarchy(nodes, indent = 0)
  return unless nodes   # stops the recursion if there are no nodes

  nodes.each do |node|
    puts "#{'  ' * indent}#{node.name}"
    # here is the list of all children generated, do not care about how
    # deep the subtree is, cause recursion...
    print_page_hierarchy(node.children, indent + 1)
  end
end
```

test

```
print_page_hierarchy(nodes)
# => page_1
#      page_1a
#    page_2
#      page_2a
#      page_2b
#        page_2bi
#        page_2bii
#        page_2biii
#      page_2c
#    page_3
#    page_4
#    page_5
```